# How to reduce padding, margin in Bootstrap template

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, padding, margin, font-size

Downloaded "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/heroes/", removed all sections in index.html except "hero" & "sign-up form". There's too much white space between these two and I can't figure out how to access the specific css code to reduce padding and/or margin.

Also need to reduce font size of text. Any pointers?

Comment: [Bootstrap uses classes for just about everything](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/)

Comment: Thanks @AStombaugh for explaining. The puzzling thing is, I don't really have any css file in the assets folder on my server. I thought all css & js functionality was being accessed via CDN. Still trying to figure out a way to change settings in all the classes that will fix my issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstraps already it's probably easiest to stick with Bootstraps instead of writing custom CSS if you don't need to. Looking at the source code for the link you provided I can see several classes that are affecting the spacing and sizing of the elements on your page.

### Margins and Padding

- The `py-5` class is adding padding to the top and bottom of each element the class is applied to on the page creating white space.
- The `pt-5` class is adding padding to the top of elements.
- The `my-5` class is adding margin before and after elements.
- It also looks like many nested element have a `mb-#` class also adding a margin to the bottom of elements, maybe another place to minimize white space.

You can change these classes to decrease the size of the margin and padding. For example you could try replacing `my-5` with `my-2` to decrease the margin or replace it with `my-0` to remove the margin.

You can read the documentation using the link [@AStombaugh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/ajinkya) commented to your question for more details about [Bootstrap Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/).

### Font Size

A similar process can be used for decreasing the font size. Seeing the `display-5` class in your source code, the Bootstrap documentation on [Typography](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/) is a good place to start.

The documentation on [Text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/) may also be helpful with adjusting the font sizes and line height.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler Robots for explaining. The puzzling thing is, I don't really have any css file in the assets folder on my server. I thought all css & js functionality was being accessed via CDN. Still trying to figure out a way to change settings in all the classes you've mentioned.

Comment: Your welcome @pujji . For the CDN you are accessing are the CSS and JS files managed by Bootstraps or do you manage the files those files?

Comment: If you do not manage those files you will not be able to make the changes you are describing. You shouldn't really need to change the CSS settings for the classes to make the adjustments you want, instead change the class names that are being referenced in the HTML class attributes.